# Cannot deploy weblogic server application that contains log4j 2.9.x

Tags: log4j, weblogic

I am not able to start application it gives below exception :

Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
At com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknownsource)com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown source)

Application got started after replacing below jars

Log4j-1.2-api-2.9.1.jar
Log4j-api-2.9.1.jar
Log4j-core-2.9.1.jar
Log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar

With

Log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar
Log4j-api-2.8.2jar
Log4j-core-2.8.2.jar
Log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.9.0 there are classes compiled in java 9.
One workaround is to remove them from log4j-api-2.x.y.jar